# Send sms via aws-sdk-js

Tags: node.js, sms, amazon-sns, aws-sdk-js

What is the way to send sms using aws-sdk-js ?
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js

Is there is proper code available from amazon for this(javascript).
I refered the below docs, but is not enough informative
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SMS.html

This code actually worked for me.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
    region: 'ap-southwest-1',
    accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    secretAccessKey: 'xxxxSSSSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
});

var sns = new AWS.SNS();

var params = {
    Message: 'Alert! emssage.....',
    MessageStructure: 'string',
    PhoneNumber: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
};

sns.publish(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else console.log(data);
});
```

Any better way of doing this with adding Sender ID and all?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a SNS topic and subscribe to a Mobile number. Then you can use SDK to publish the topic. This way you can send SMS.

Visit [Send SMS using AWS SDK](http://www.tryyourskill.com/aws/send-sms-using-aws-sdk) example given in java.

You can refer this link for Node.js [publish sns](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#publish-property)

```
PublishRequest _PublishRequest = null;
    PublishResult _PublishResult = null;
    try{
        _PublishRequest = new PublishRequest("arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:081701745661:sendSMS","MessageBody","Subject");
        _PublishResult = SNSClient.publish(_PublishRequest);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Got an error in method sendSMSNotification: " + e.getMessage());                
        }
    return _PublishResult.getMessageId();
```

Comment: Actually I was in search of a stable NodeJS code, not JAVA. Java code is readily available in website.\

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
var params = {
    Message: 'Alert! emssage.....',
    MessageStructure: 'string',
    PhoneNumber: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID': {
        DataType: 'String',
        StringValue: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
    }
};`
```

But pls sure that you're in supporting country.
You can check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_supported-countries.html)